# XCcode9.3/iOS11.3 fmdb/sqlite will be crash

Tags: sqlite, fmdb, ios11.3

`XCcode9.3` run project when First time In `Debug`, `fmdb/sqlite`  crashes most of the time.

some info is: `"BUG IN CLIENT OF sqlite3.dylib:` illegal multi-threaded access to database connection"

Did some changes for `iOS11.3?`